# dropping table gives "foreign key constraint fail" error

Tags: mysql, grails

The structure of address table is as shown in the attached image.

I am wondering why when deleting this table "foreign key constraint violation" error occurs. It doesn't look like this table has a foreign key.

**Structure of address table**

[image: Structure of address table]

**Error deleting table**

[image: Error deleting table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the direction wrong. Dropping a table will result in a FK constraint violation if *another* table references it.

In other words, the constraint will be in a different table, perhaps a column that references `id` in your `address` table. You need to find the constraint and remove it before you can drop this table.

Comment: does this mean if A table references table B then I should delete table A first and only then B? My intention is to drop both A and B tables. Thanks!

Comment: @user734861, that depends entirely upon any other constraints that may exist. It's not usually necessary to remove the entire referencing table, just the constraint itself. But if, as you say, you're getting rid of both tables involved in the constraint, then yes, delete the referencing one first.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

See Relation view of other table at bottom of other table structure view;

It will shows list of foreign key setups/links. This table is referenced. Remove it.
[see example](http://prntscr.com/8j45sq)